# HP Fortify scan issue:Password Management: Password in HTML Form

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, fortify

I used Fortify software to scan my web project and encountered great difficulties

Issue:Password Management: Password in HTML Form

```
<input name="pin" type="password" data-rule-required="true" value="${pin}">
```

type="password" can let me show ** in HTML page for user

How can I modify this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove value   will pass the fortify software

Answer (score 3):

Fortify uses a number of different analysis techniques on the backend. Some are more sophisticated, like data and call analysis. Others are very simplistic syntax analyses, looking for unsafe functions.

One of the syntax analyses rules looks for the word "password" anywhere in the source files, surmising that it could represent a hard-coded password. However, often it is just a variable that is named "password"/"pwd" or part of the HTML (as in this case). They're pretty quick to review, and just mark them as "not an issue" and suppress so that they do not turn up in future scans.

Answer (score 0):

Fortify can have a lot of noise in the results and it takes a little bit to figure out what is real and what is not.  It is getting better, but the Password ones are VERY OFTEN false positives.  Just mark that one suppressed or "Not an Issue".